# filter with undeclared type of array in Angular 2 Component

Tags: angular, typescript

My component have a function that filtering an undeclared type of array.

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    public TaskList: []=[];
    public TaskTypes: any;

    constructor(){}

    ngOnInit() {

    this.TaskList=getTaskList();

          this.TaskTypes = [
            { test: "All Task", value: "all", class: "bg-primary", id: "all-task", icon: "fa-tasks", TaskList: this.TaskList },
            { test: "Ongoing", value: "ongoing", class: "bg-warning", id: "ongoing-task", icon: "fa-plug", TaskList: this.TaskList.filter(o => o.Status.includes("A")) },
            { test: "Hold", value: "hold", class: "bg-danger", id: "hold-task", icon: "fa-hand-paper", TaskList: this.TaskList.filter(o => o.Status.includes("H")) },
            { test: "Completed", value: "completed", class: "bg-success", id: "completed-task", icon: "fa-calendar-check", TaskList: this.TaskList.filter(o => o.Status.includes("C")) }
          ];
      }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

I can not create a class.ts file for TaskList because properties is not fixed for TaskList but a property 'Status' is fixed.

everything is working fine but i am getting error while compile.

> ERROR in src/app/home/home.component.ts(85,142): error TS2339:
>   Property 'Status' does not exist on type 'never'.
>   src/app/home/home.component.ts(86,138): error TS2339: Property
>   'Status' does not exist on type 'never'.
>   src/app/home/home.component.ts(87,158): error TS2339: Property
>   'Status' does not exist on type 'never'.

what is the best way for these kind of filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
public TaskList: []=[];
```

that's where TS's "type 'never'" error comes from. Declare it as an array of `any`s:

```
public TaskList: any[] = [];
```

Here's documentation on type 'never':

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Answer (score 0):

Just add "any" to the array type
public TaskList: any[] = [];